# Add prefix to every line shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a input file

Input:

```
aaa_bbbbbbbbb
aaaa_bbbbbb
aa_hhhhhh
```

and I need the output:

```
aaa_1 aaa_bbbbbbbbb
aaaa_2 aaaa_bbbbbb
aa_3 aa_hhhhhh
```

i.e characters till _ and then a line number in every line.

I have this script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/export/home/rachit.singla/f1.txt"
while read line
do
   grep $line uniqfiles.txt| sed "s/./$line    /"| sed 's/ /_/' >>./final.txt;
done< "$file"
```

output:

```
aaa_ aaa_bbbbbbbbb
aaaa_ aaaa_bbbbbb
aa_ aa_hhhhhh
```

How to add the numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more straight forward to use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F_ '{print $1""FS""NR, $0}' file
aaa_1 aaa_bbbbbbbbb
aaaa_2 aaaa_bbbbbb
aa_3 aa_hhhhhh
```

Or, a bit nicer:

```
awk -F_ '{printf "%s%s%d %s\n", $1, FS, NR, $0}'
```

That is, set `_` as field separator and then print the first field followed by that field separator and line number. Then, a space and the full line.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat -n <file> | sed 's/^ \{1,5\}\([0-9]*\)\t\(.*_\)/\2\1 \2/'
```

note: `cat`'s -n adds spaces for the line numbers and is followed by a tab which both have to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This is using sed as requested:

```
sed = input.txt |  sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)_/\2_\1 /'
```

Comment: Even though it works, piping three `sed`s seems to overkilling, since a simple `awk` can make it. Also, it is a bit fragile and can break at any little change of format.

Comment: @fedorqui I agree with you, I'll preferr using awk but the question is asking (see the tags) for sed ;)

Comment: Well, the OP is using grep + sed and tagging with [sed], true, but I think it is still fair to consider programs that are also in a system having such tools. And `awk` or `perl` can be those.